Why does a DVD-RW with data on it show as empty?
I have an old DVD-RW disk which shows as empty in both Windows 11 Explorer and ImgBurn. However I know there is data on it because the written part is clearly visible on the data side. But I do not know if the session was closed etc.
I suspect the data to be files, not a DVD video. How can I recover this data?
Here is the output of ImgBurn if it may help:
PIONEER BD-RW   BDR-UD03 1.10 (USB)
Current Profile: DVD-RW

Disc Information:
Status: Incomplete
State of Last Session: Incomplete
Erasable: Yes
Sessions: 1
Free Sectors: 1.833.008
Free Space: 3.754.000.384 bytes
Free Time: 407:22:08 (MM:SS:FF)
Next Writable Address: 464880
MID: RITEKW01
Supported Write Speeds: 1x; 2x

TOC Information:
Session 1... (LBA: 0)
-> Track 01  (Mode 1, LBA: 0 - -1)
-> LeadOut  (LBA: 0)

Pre-recorded Information:
Manufacturer ID: RITEKW01

Physical Format Information (Last Recorded):
Book Type: DVD-RW
Part Version: 2
Disc Size: 120 mm
Maximum Read Rate: Not Specified
Number of Layers: 1
Track Path: Parallel Track Path (PTP)
Linear Density: 0.267 um/bit
Track Density: 0.74 um/track
First Physical Sector of Data Area: 196.608
Last Physical Sector of Data Area: 196.608
Last Physical Sector in Layer 0: 0

Format Capacities:
DT: 0x03 - NB: 62500864 (0x03B9B000) - TDP: 2048
FT: 0x00 - NB: 2297888 (0x00231020) - TDP: 2048
FT: 0x10 - NB: 2297888 (0x00231020) - TDP: 16
FT: 0x15 - NB: 2297888 (0x00231020) - TDP: 16

Performance (Write Speed):
Descriptor 1...
-> B0: 0x00; B1: 0x00; B2: 0x00; B3: 0x00
-> EL: 2298495 (0x0023127F)
-> RS: 1.385 KB/s (1x) - WS: 1.385 KB/s (1x)
Descriptor 2...
-> B0: 0x00; B1: 0x00; B2: 0x00; B3: 0x00
-> EL: 2298495 (0x0023127F)
-> RS: 2.770 KB/s (2x) - WS: 2.770 KB/s (2x)


If the disc was not finalized, you need the program used to write the DVD in order to read it. Which program was it and was it on another computer?

@harrymc it was probably around 2003, no idea which program. I have now looked at it with IsoBuster, it's a video dvd after all. Probably Windows XP Windows Movie Maker or so.

Most likely, the DVD was not finalized.
When one initially writes to a DVD, only data, not the full file system, is put on the optical disk. (That also applies to writable CD's.) The file system is kept on the PC that wrote the data, not on the optical disk, until the disk is closed, or finalized.
If you still have the PC that wrote the data, and the file layout for the DVD was not lost, it is possible the disk could be finalized now, and then it would be readable on other PC's.
It also might be possible to recover data from that DVD, using tools such as CD Recovery Toolbox Free or one of the alternatives listed at Wondershare or AlternativeTo. Before using software, check it at VirusTotal.
